# IDE freezes when cancelling the "Validating breakpoint location" dialogbox

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, ide, freeze

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3 (build 14.0.25424.00).
When I load a relatively large solution and all projects have been loaded, a debugger dialog box appears displaying "Validating breakpoint location..:"

[image]

The process of validating breakpoint locations never ends. If I press the Cancel button, the IDE freezes completely and I have to kill the devenv process.

I've tried `devenv /ResetSettings` but it didn't help.

My solution contains 20+ class library projects, two web-projects (using node/gulp)

Anyone else experienced this? Any solutions?

Comment: I was able to load my solution again. I searched for solution user options files (.suo) in my solution and deleted the one under a directory with the same name as my solution. I still wonder what caused the IDE to freeze.